# How can i add to allow any amount of dashes to this REGEX

Tags: regex

I want this regex to allow for dashes "-". Any amount will do.

```
(?:\d*[a-z]){0,1}\d*$
```

Currently this regex allows for any amount of numbers and only 1 alphanumeric character. I want this to also allow for any amount of dashes "-".

Comment: Why not use `?` instead of `{0,1}`?

Comment: Any number of dashes where?  Anywhere in the string, including the beginning and/or end?  Are multiple consecutive dashes ok?  Can you edit the question to show some examples of strings that should match *and* strings that shouldn't?

Comment: Your regex already allows any number of dashes since it is not anchored... It will match `---------a` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a dash:

```
^([\d-]*[a-z]?|[a-z]?[\d-]*|[\d-]*[a-z]?[\d-]*)$
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vmdq

Comment: hmm for some reason it isnt matching and returns false if i enter something like: "242-2342"

Comment: @thesandman - The regex as it was required a single letter. I updated the answer...

Comment: That's because your pattern wants to always match a word character at the end of your string. @JosephSilber, I'd have gone with: [-\d]+[a-z]{0,1}\d+$ myself.

Comment: @Josh - By now I'm so confused, I don't even know what the OP wants to match. To be honest, I'm not sure *he* has a firm grasp on what it is he wants...

Comment: ok my mistake. i'm confused myself a bit in the process. 1. Allow any amount of numbers or dashes. 2. only allow 1 alpha character. Does not matter what it starts or ends with in the string.

Comment: to add to that, it doesnt matter what the last chacter is, it can be a number, letter or dash, just as long as there are not more than 1 total alpha characters in the string. thanks!!

Comment: @thesandman - OK. I've updated my answer with a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Joseph Silber - you nailed it. that is perfect. great job and thanks for the help!!